# Uploading Temperature data (DHT22) to Thingspeak with an ENC28J60

Tags: sensors, arduino-pro-mini, ethernet, web-server

So, I've gotten my module working pretty well. It logs data from the DHT22 and sends it to a 192 address on my LAN. However, I'd like to log and graph the data.

I figured thingspeak is a decent platform for that. However, I have no experience doing so, and I'm not sure where to start. All the examples use the "official" arduino shield. I've only found ONE example bit of code, but it uses the Dallas One Wire temp module. [Link](https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/65275256/1011665768/name/Blank_Thingspeak_Ethercard.ino)

I'm in over my head, and have no idea how to switch from the One wire to the DHT22. Thanks for the help!

I'm using a clone arduino pro mini, 5V 16mhz, 328.

If there's a better platform than thingspeak, I'm open. All I want to do is graph and visualize the DHT22 sensor readings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/*
| Post temp. values from a DS18B20 to ThingSpeak using the Ethercard interface based on the 
| ENC28J60 chip.
| Based on the Ethercard example from www.jeelabs.org
| Phil Grant Jan 2014
*/
#include <EtherCard.h>
// change these settings to match your own setup
#define APIKEY  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

//DHT Setup
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 2     // what pin we're connected to
// Uncomment whatever type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)  
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
byte mymac[] = { 0xXX,0xXX,0xXX,0xXX,0xXX,0xXX };

char website[] PROGMEM = "api.thingspeak.com";

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
uint32_t timer;
Stash stash;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);
    dht.begin(); //Initializate DHT
  Serial.println("\n[webClient]");

  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0) 
    Serial.println( "Failed to access Ethernet controller");
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
    Serial.println("DHCP failed");

  ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip);  
  ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip);  

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
    Serial.println("DNS failed");

  ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 60000; //Transmit every minute
    delay(2000);  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity(); // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  char h_buffer[10];
  String Hstring = dtostrf(h,0,5,h_buffer); //Convert Humidity value to String

  float t = dht.readTemperature(); // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  //float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  char t_buffer[10];
  String Tstring = dtostrf(t,0,5,t_buffer); //Convert Temperature value to String

    byte sd = stash.create();
    stash.print("field1=");
    stash.println(Hstring);
    stash.print("&field2=");
    stash.println(Tstring);
    stash.save();

    // generate the header with payload - note that the stash size is used,
    // and that a "stash descriptor" is passed in as argument using "$H"
    Stash::prepare(PSTR("POST /update HTTP/1.1" "\r\n" 
                        "Host: $F" "\r\n" 
                        "Connection: close" "\r\n" 
                        "X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: $F" "\r\n" 
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n" 
                        "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n" 
                        "\r\n" 
                        "$H"),
            website, PSTR(APIKEY), stash.size(), sd);

    // send the packet - this also releases all stash buffers once done
    ether.tcpSend();
  }
}
```